# Script doesn't run after loaded a html file into a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with my page.
When i click on a link on my page, it will load a external html inside a div in the page. the div with the id="div1". (AJAX)

**It works perfect.**

the external html-page which has been loaded **includes a div with the id="rex"**.

My Problem is:

i have a script, which must add content in the div (with the id="rex")
i wrote the script in the external file, but it doesn't run.
probably i must write my script in the page and not in the external html-file.

here the script Number 3:

```
$('#rex').ready(function() {
    var url="genredetail.php";
    var activitydetail = sessionStorage.activitydetail;

    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        $.each(json.genredetail,function(i,item){
            if(item.name == activitydetail){
                $('<p class="excerpt">' + item.beschreibung3 + '</p>').appendTo('#rex');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This script must run when the external file (with the div id="rex") has been loaded. But it doesn't :-(
What can i do? Is the problem that the script runs before the page get the `<div id="rex">`?

Thanks in advance, and sorry my bad english :-S

A picture for more clearness
[image]

the script number 1 makes the link.
when i click on a link, the script number 2, let the site load in the div1.
The script number 3 must fill the div="rex" with informations. but it doesn't run.

Comment: Is your script not getting called at all or is it failing somewhere?

Comment: Can you use $(document).ready(function(){}) instead of $('#rex').ready(function(){}) ? Any particular reason behind it?

Comment: the script is not getting called

Comment: no, i can't use it. it doesn't run :-(

Comment: Are you getting any errors? This should work see link http://jsfiddle.net/e8vyjahv/2/

Comment: Aman Baloch thanks for the links, but it doesn't run... 
My problem is, that the script doesn't run, in the external file which has been loaded in the dom, doesnt run.

Comment: aman Baloch, i update now my question. maybe its my question not very clear.

Comment: Is script number 3 inside single-project.html?

Comment: Also your single-project.html doesn't need html, head and body elements, It should only include <div id="rex"></div>

Comment: Aman Baloch, i tried it to write the script in the single-project file. but that wasn't a good idea. Now i tried it to implement in the script number 2. can i send you the script?

Comment: Can you share a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) link?

Answer (score 1):

try onload

```
$('div').on("load","#rex",function() {

do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setInterval, so it check the element rex every 0.5 s

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if ($("#rex").length)
            {
                var url="genredetail.php";
                var activitydetail = sessionStorage.activitydetail;

                $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                $.each(json.genredetail,function(i,item){
                if(item.name == activitydetail){

                $('<p class="excerpt">' + item.beschreibung3 + '</p>').appendTo('#rex');
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: no, dreamweaver say that it isn't a correct code... :-S

Comment: above code is javascript code. if you put it in HTML, you should wrap it with <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the script if it is already loaded. As you said you are loading the external html inside a div, does it include the external js file you are using? if not please include it.

Comment: one time i tried to include it, and one time i insert the script in the page with <script>...</script>